# Automatically create new media folder for each blog post on Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

When I upload a new image to Orchard CMS all the media goes into the `/blog/Media/Default/BlogPost/blog/` folder by default. Can I have it default to an automatically created folder for each blog post?

Comment: Not without going into the code.